# insufficient funds for gas * price + value in Java Error

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, blockchain, solidity

While I deploying the contract on blockchain on adding transaction it gives error...

```
private static final Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("HTTPS://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d11459c1c17049628f462a1492c7df36"));

private static final Credentials hostCredentials = Credentials.create("666A82FC33F8134577A7BEB1BDEAA689BB72740178727691D63032432B83E0FB");

private static final BigInteger gasLimit = BigInteger.valueOf(4712388L);
private static final BigInteger gasPrice =  BigInteger.valueOf(20000000000L);

 public String depart_wallet(String code) {
    String walletCode = "";
    switch(code) {
        case "ct_01" : 
                walletCode = "83E094366642F531189D56DF33AC870DB53AF8C7F7F60A7A8B20CB85BC43A59F";
                break;
        case "ft_01" :
                walletCode = "666A82FC33F8134577A7BEB1BDEAA689BB72740178727691D63032432B83E0FB";
                break;
        case "ms_01" :
                walletCode = "3F0B5C58378DE554534A5A8C630AAC075886E74A6B3229000AE78F4500E153E3";
                break;
        case "st_01" :
                walletCode = "3B69CC479DBAC9B02D2B7C39F7829A2E5DF850203A1766355D854DD89FCC6848";
                break;
        case "hr_01" :
                walletCode = "3F1E2BD4EF8941731D244359F0CDF1EF079E5EAFFD57EA6D31ADDEB55E20D426";
                break;
        case "mf_01" :
                walletCode = "C6FD20908CDC2326A8A5E366228C149FA7632E9C4EF035F5B7EBEE1A04158B7E";
                break;

    }
    return walletCode;
}
```

I am going to take the code from the web.

and send it through the method above to get the wallet address and deploy it.

```
public void budgetAdd(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) throws Exception {

    String department_code = req.getParameter("dept_code");

    String deptWallet = depart_wallet(department_code);

    Credentials dept_AccountNumber = Credentials.create(deptWallet);

    String contractAddress2 = Materal.deploy(web3j, dept_AccountNumber, gasPrice, gasLimit).send().getContractAddress();

    int price = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("money"));
    BigInteger ethers = null;

    if(price < 100000) {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(1));
    }
    else if((100000 < price) && (price < 300000)) {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(1.25));
    }
    else if ((300000 < price) && (price < 500000)) {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(1.5));
    }
    else if ((500000 < price) && (price < 800000)) {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(1.8));
    }
    else if ((800000 < price) && (price < 1000000)) {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(2));
    }
    else {
        ethers = etherToWei(new BigDecimal(2.25));
    }

    byte[] name = stringToBytes32(department_code);

    Materal dept = Materal.load(contractAddress2, web3j, hostCredentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    String hash = dept.buyMaterial(new BigInteger("0"), name, ethers).send().getTransactionHash();

    String purpose = req.getParameter("purpose");

    HashVO vos = new HashVO();
    vos.setDepartment_code(department_code);
    vos.setE_subject(purpose);
    vos.setE_hashcode(hash);

    int insertCnt = dao.insertLog(vos);
    if(insertCnt == 1) {
        System.out.println("등록되었습니다.");
    }
}
```

I want to deploy And ether trade finish, insert to My Oracle.
but my code can't deploy.

Maybe gasLimit is low?
However, the same error occurred when the GasLimit was changed to 6721975.

Yesterday it worked properly without errors, but now it didn't work. Can you give me an answer to this error?

Comment: Always when you ask questions where you "get error", you need to actually tell us those errors, clearly. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "Yesterday it worked properly without errors, but now it didn't work" - so, what changed since yesterday?

Comment: Yesterday gasLimit is 4712388L,
after an error has occurredI changed 6721975. There is no modified code except gasLimit.